# Is it OK to use personal email ID for faculty job applications or should we use (current) institute's ID

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

I am about a graduate from my university. Will it be OK to use my personal email if I am looking for faculty jobs/postdoc positions. Will it somehow give a negative impact on my application as compared to those who apply through any institution's link?

Comment: Note that outside of academia this would be a non-question - one always uses a personal email. Note also you can CC your institutional  address to show that you do have it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have an institutional email that will still be accessible for the foreseeable future, I would suggest using it. When I see applications for academic positions that use @hotmail.com or something, I sometimes (subconsciously perhaps) judge the application to be of lesser desirability.

**However**

This momentary judgement of the applicant's email address is quickly dismissed if the rest of the application is quality. If you are using a good @gmail.com email address or something similar, there is no shame in that. *It should go without saying*, but obviously do not apply for faculty positions with an email such as pick_butts@yahoo.com (or whatever). Even an email like sparkle.38@gmail.com should be avoided.

I would suggest creating a nice gmail address specific for just your applications.

> Roger.M.Turley@gmail.com (assuming one's name was actually Roger M. Turley)

This will allow you to be professional in your presentation as well as funnel all necessary correspondence to a specific and single purpose email account.

Comment: Don't underestimate the importance of using an email address that you'll continue to have- In the past I've tried to contact candidates whose previous institutional emails had been shut down and it simply wasn't possible to reach them.

Comment: Don't use a gmail address if one of the qualifications for the job is that you have an understanding of computer security and privacy. You might not care that google read your mail and use it to target advertising, but other people do, and might be shocked that you don't.

Comment: @MichaelKay - email is completely and utterly insecure by it's very design. Anyone who thinks that using a different email provider is more secure knows literally jack shit about electronic security. Using PGP encryption is an absolute minimum to consider emails even remotely secure.

Comment: @MichaelKay I would auto reject someone who believes that applications should be rejected solely because the applicant uses one of the largest email providers in the world

Comment: There's a difference between using a service that's capable of being attacked and using one that's regularly and systematically intercepted by the company that provides the service. Certainly, advising people to use gmail as something that looks professional seems way off the mark. Indeed, recruiters could legitimately refuse to send personal information to a gmail address on the grounds that doing so breaches privacy rules.

Comment: Other email providers are available.

Comment: @MichaelKay: The last university I was working in was using Google Mail as the backend for its university email system. "Google can read them" is a red herring. If you have something to hide, you use a burner email at the very least (more realistically, a properly encrypted or even deniable channel of communication) and you certainly don't reuse it for anything associated with your name, such as job applications.

Comment: Presumably (one hopes) the University had a contract with google to ensure the privacy of its communications. Individuals using a free gmail account don't have that luxury.

Comment: Also note, it's not a question of whether YOU have anything to hide. If you use a free gmail account, Google builds a profile of any individual who sends you mail on that account, including, for example, people who write references for you.

Comment: @MichaelKay Is anything truly private in this world? I'm pretty sure than my current employer screens all of my emails anyway right now. In fact, I signed paperwork acknowledging that anything I do on an institution machine "including all forms of electronic communication" is property of my employer. I had to sign a similar agreement when I worked at a private company a few years ago. I've just learned that the only way to ensure privacy is to never engage in the public domain.

Comment: If you don't care about your privacy (and that of the people who correspond with you), then do what you like. But please don't advise others to use gmail as if this is going to make them look professional.

Comment: For a personal address I would suggest to pick some nice commercial service. They start very cheap and many are much more serious. Hotmail is a no go anyway (seldom saw anything good from them) and GMail is the typical "I use the first service I heard of" choice nowadays. Privacy is another factor, but something that isn't popular in my spam folder is a plus to make a good impression. And you're more likely to still get ``firstname.lastname@`` or even ``lastname@`` there.

Answer (score 10):

No, there's no negative impact. In many universities your email account stops working after you leave, and you'll definitely want potential employers to have valid contact information. And everyone knows and understands this.

And your current university will be listed in your resume and application, and will be confirmed by other means than having an email address.

Answer (score 7):

There is a third possibility here, which is also worth considering: establish a professional address that is linked to a professional society rather than your current institution.

While not all societies do this, some will offer you an address at their domain as one of your benefits of membership (IEEE and ACM are examples). If the professional societies in your field do this, it can be an easy way to have a long-term professional email address that is respectable and clearly indicates your professional affiliation without being tied to your current institution (e.g., `sjaffrey@ieee.org`).

Comment: And most such professional email addresses can be auto forwarded to any more convenient one if you like.  ACM, for example, does this.

Comment: One of my friends got criticized by a recruiter for having an email on a "non-serious" domain ieee.org. "What is this? A yell or something?" Come to think, it's even for the best: let the incompetent recruiters filter themselves out.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to show a distinct level of professionalism is to take the time to register your own domain. As this will be used for professional purposes, its name should reflect that usage.

With a bit of learning you can use the same domain to host a resume. This can all be done for under USD$20-30 per year so beware of unscrupulous services offing to do it for you for much more.

Any employer is likely to be (perhaps even subconsciously) impressed by `Firstname@FirstnameLastname.com` vs. `somejoker29231@gmail.com`.

Comment: If you use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) you can host static files for free with custom domain HTTPS

Comment: I would either go with ``mail@firstnamelastname`` of if I can get it for any common top level domain ``firstname@lastname``. Avoid "new" TLDs like ``.website``. Ironically, not even ``.email`` is a good choice for e-mail. People are just not used to them and do not remember them correctly and they make a not that serious impression because they are (still) less known.

Comment: Hosting an email server can run into a whole set of problems. If you don't set up the server correctly many receiving and intermediary servers will not accept your email. Google is notorious for this.

Comment: @allo I have seen a good exception to your rule about 'new' TLDs - I saw someone who had the domain firstname.surname where their surname was a TLD. Of course this option isn't available to most of us, but I see that e.g. .green is a TLD with public registration

Comment: @stuart10 I think that's even worse than other unfamiliar TLDs. Non-technical people likely won't recognize firstname.surname as a valid domain and will think something is missing. Even if you know 'surname' is a TLD people might wonder if you just forgot the TLD or not.

Comment: @NDEthos Most people should not host their own e-mail server. But there are cheap offers to use mail with your own domain. Most domain registrars allow free e-mail forwards and many (even small) webhosting packages come with e-mail (often only a 100 mb mailbox or forwarding and 3 aliases, but this may be enough for you). And some e-mail providers allow you to use your own domain with their service.